# Calling function inside callback throws error in Angular

Tags: javascript, cordova

I use a [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-screensize) which has two callback functions:

```
window.plugins.screensize.get(this.screensize_success, this.screensize_error);
```

Next, in the success callback, I do:

```
screensize_success(result)
{
    console.log(result); // <--- works fine
    console.log("##### height: "+result.height); // <--- works fine
    this.get_highest(result); // <--- throws an error
}
get_highest(result)
{
  return Math.max(result.height,result.width);
}
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_highest'
>   of null

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're losing the `this` context when the callback is called.

Simplest way to remedy this is to bind the callbacks to `this`:

```
window.plugins.screensize.get(this.screensize_success.bind(this), this.screensize_error.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly prefer to set function as variables to be easily reused in your program such as :

```
var get_highest = function (result)
{
  return Math.max(result.height,result.width);
}
```

and call it without this :

```
get_highest(result);
```